# can't get a hover event to work on a sibling of a target element using jquery ui duration paramater or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is to change the background color of an element and one of its siblings that is higher in the DOM but in the same parent on hover. I was able to use css transition to change the first element but i couldn't get the sibling to change. so I looked into  [jquery UI addClass effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/)

I wanted the code below to work since I couldn't get a css solution to work, the goal was to change both elements on hover

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.circletag').hover(function() {
             $(this).addClass( "red");
             $(this).parent().find('title').addClass('red', 2000);
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('red', 5000);
            $(this).parent().find('title').removeClass('red', 2000);
        });
})
```

I was able to get a fade effect on the $(this) elements but the `.title` element is not showing any changes at all.

when `.circletag` is hovered I would like `.circletag` backgroud to change and the `.title` background to change at the same time over a 2 second interval. If It cant be done with css which is the way I would prefer the solution I would appreciate a jquery one.

Also I'm curios to know why the console says

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

    .ui-helper-hidden {
```

Why does the duration not work in this addClass function when im using jquery ui? So weird for me.
why is it that when the mouse is moves off the element it does not take 5 seconds to remove the class? it looks like the css transition rule is calling the shots.

basically I want the div with the class of `.title`'s backgound and `.circletag` background to fade in and out on hover of `.circletag`.
**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5NM8Z/1/)**

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $('.circletag').hover(function() {
         $(this).addClass( "red");
         $(this).parent().find('.title').addClass('red', 2000);
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('red', 5000);
        $(this).parent().find('.title').removeClass('red', 2000);
    });
 })
```

You need to specify the class selector in 'find' function..
Let me know :)

Comment: thanks. I got it to work with your help and using transition on the title element do you know what the SyntaxError: syntax error
 .ui-helper-hidden { that i get in firefox is for. I would like to know why the duration in the addClass ui doesnt seem to  work. thanks

Comment: how do you include the css? Do you have something like this "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css"/>" (the right one) or are you wrongly using a <script> tag?

Comment: I think it should solve your problem ;) Please, mark the answer as the correct one..

Comment: I don't get the error any more but Im not done yet. lets say  I dont want the to use css transition any more. so right im using duration and I cant get it to work and i used link <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">. I have $(this).addClass( "red" , 4000); can you show a working example . then I will close

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(this).parent().find('.title').addClass('red', 2000);
```

you need to use ".title" inside your find() if you are referring a class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5NM8Z/2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but lets say I didnt want to use css transition any more can you show me code that work with the duration paramater in the addClass function when using jquery UI when you get a chance. thanks for your help